# Can "both" change the meaning of a sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

Is there any difference in meaning between:

> Both my two friends moved the heavy table.

and

> My two friends moved the heavy table.

?

Answer (score 1):

It’s redundant to say “both...two” because “both” means “the two (of)”. “Both (of) my friends” and “my two friends” are *both* normal ways to talk about two friends.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on context.

Here is a possible interpretation:

> *Each of* my two friends moved the heavy table.

This could mean that my two friends moved the heavy table, but they moved it independently of each other. (The table was moved at least twice, once by one friend, then once by the other friend.) It doesn't *have* to mean that, but it would be unusual if it didn't. Normally, when you use the word *each*, you treat the things mentioned as separate from each other.

---

> *Both of* my two friends moved the heavy table.

This could mean that they moved the table in cooperation. It was moved once, with the two of them combining their effort.

---

However, the *both* version of the sentence is somewhat ambiguous, because it doesn't *have* to describe the situation where there was joint effort. In order for that to be made explicit, you would phrase it differently:

> *Working together*, (both of) my (two) friends moved the heavy table.
>   (Both of) my (two) friends *jointly* moved the heavy table.

In colloquial speech, *both of* and *two* can be combined to provide emphasis—and to *imply* that there was joint effort.

But, *syntactically*, it doesn't necessitate that meaning, and using *both of* and *two* is unnecessary. (And in a different construction—such as *it took both of the two of them*—combining them would actually sound wrong.)